# Upgrading .NET 4.0 to 4.6.1 "Properties referred by the Dependent Role" Error

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, edmx

I read a few Stack Overflow posts but I am still confused on how to fix this error.

I am working on .NET 4.0 ASP.NET Webform Solution with many projects, which was configured with 4.0. I am using Visual Studio 2015 and building with 4.6.1 and getting 10 errors that looks like the following

> Error 111: Properties referred by the Dependent Role TableDetail must be a subset of the key of the EntityType PUBModel.TableDetail referred to by the Dependent Role in the referential constraint for Relationship PUBModel.SeverityTypeTableDetail.

When I click on the error, it takes me to the .edmx data model page. I right click on Validate menu item and still compiles with the same error.

I am not experienced in solving these errors. The .edmx only shows the database relations between the tables.

Comment: I would suggest to drop your .edmx file and regenerate it. I believe this should solve your issue. 
Note: After dropping your edmx file also remove/comment out the existing connection string in your config file.

Answer (score 0):

Update - I deleted the mapping in my edmx file and used the Wizard to regenerated the mapping from all the selected tables. However, it generated a very different edmx file and got different build errors. Next step, I right clicked on the project and selected Undo Pending Changes and manually set the framework from 4.0 to 4.6.1. It compiled without the edmx related error message. Hope this help others.